# How to fix return Ajax in a div without return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a web application, and i have a problem with a return of Ajax.

I can see the result of the return of AJAX, but my problem is that this result appears and then disappears. I found a solution that is return false, the problem being that once the display is done and I return false, my div remains on the page but I can not reuse the button on which I made my onclick (to call my javascript function and so the ajax call).

If someone has a solution.

This is the code :

```
<input class="Admin-Bouton" type="submit" onclick="affOtp();return false" value="Générer" form="formParametres" />

<div id="syntheseOTP"></div>

function affOtp() {
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vue/ressources/affOtp.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { idEmploye: nom },
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                document.getElementById("syntheseOTP").innerHTML = msg;
            },
            error: function(resu, statut, erreur) {
                console.log(erreur);
                alert("papa");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Remove `document-ready` handler i.e. `$(function(){  ... })` from code and use `type="button" `

Comment: Hey Satpal, you answer is perfect but i must keep the type="submit" ... I don't know if you have solution with it

Comment: Put the return false at the end of your ajax call, not inline on the button attributes. Or else you need to create an anonymous function wrapper for the onclick and return false from that.

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl you mean to say the ajax must update the div content, and also the button must be able to click again.. which is what is not working for you.. right?

Comment: It is really not clear what is your expected behhaviour. You want to submit the `form` once ajax completes or what? You said: `I can not reuse the button on which I made my onclick` but in your posted code, if `nom` doesn't change, then you couldn't see any change by clicking same button x-times, it will return same result again and again

Comment: @A.Wolff I think he is holding on to the type submit only because there are other scripts that are already written and dependent on it .. which he doesn't want to screw up.. But what is not clear for me is `I can not reuse the button on which I made my onclick`..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy This button is use to affOTP(), but it can also display other things, it's depend about where the user click, if he select an option like OTP->EMPLOYE, this is save and the button work with OTP->EMPLOYE. And if i select other option, this is not the same type for the button, I know it's complicated but i'm obligated to do like this.

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue and more clearly explain expected behaviour

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl sounds like you will have to give us more details on the actual functionality you are doing.. Like relevant HTML, Scripts.. else this is going no where

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Your understood exactly what i search to do. Returning false make that i can't re-use the button after clicking one time on it.

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl so what you want is  ... Have the `type="submit"` and onclick of the button update the div by ajax call.. And also make sure the button is clickable after the first click too.. right

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl you want to reuse the button for what?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy This is it, it's like i have 2 buttons in one but i don't know if it's possible! If you want any other files no worry i will post them.

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl what are thouse 2 thinks that this button is suppose to do?

Comment: @madalinivascu first thing is to display an array with the type submit, and second thing is to display another array with affOTP().

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl when you submit you refresh the page,you need to trigger the ajax after the page was refreshed

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks that's a good response i'm going to find a solution with it !

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl or better remove the ajax and do it all with php

Answer (score 3):

That happen because the form will be submited and the page refresh, you could avoid that by using type `button` instead of `submit` :

```
<input id="Admin-Bouton" class="Admin-Bouton" type="button" onclick="affOtp();return false" value="Générer" form="formParametres" />
```

I suggest to attach the event click in the js code instead of inline-event `onclick` :

```
$('#Admin-Bouton').on('click', affOtp);
```

HTML will be like :

```
<input id="Admin-Bouton" class="Admin-Bouton" type="button" value="Générer" form="formParametres" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Zakaria thanks you for your response, it is good i try it but i must keep the submit type... Because this button is use for others things to. If there is no way, i'm gonna create another button.

Comment: Okay A. Wolff so it's like I do return false, but i can't reuse the button

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl You have to submit explicitly.

Comment: `but I can not reuse the button on which I made my onclick (to call my javascript function and so the ajax call).` as OP says..what about this problem?

Comment: That make no sense @RajshekarReddy the button is there if the page isn't refreshed and sure he could re-use it.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thats the `question mark` there... he has not posted enough details.. :) may be there is some other script thats breaking..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy there is no other script thats breaking, everything works well, my ajax return is ok because it's appear but juste a milisecond. It's just a problem of type with submit or button, and i think i can't use them together with a trick.

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl have you tried using `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy yes, but i don't know if i using it well. Because it was not working. It's the same resultat as returning false ( i retry it now)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Left out "return" before affOtp();

```
<input class="Admin-Bouton" type="submit" onclick="return affOtp();" value="Générer" form="formParametres" />

<div id="syntheseOTP"></div>

function affOtp() {
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vue/ressources/affOtp.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { idEmploye: nom },
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                    document.getElementById("syntheseOTP").innerHTML = msg;
                },
                error: function(resu, statut, erreur) {
                    console.log(erreur);
                    alert("papa");
                }
            });
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: If the function called on a submit's onclick returns false, it should not submit. Try it, please.

Comment: onclick="return affOtp();"

Comment: Your function has a return value so when it executes and returns the value so in your call `onclick="return fnname()"` should be written.

Comment: @codemonkey65 i have try your solution, didn't work, it's the same result that using only return false.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers are still working for you, I would recommend you to do following changes (keeping in mind you don't want to change `type="submit"`).

```
<input id="AjaxButton" class="Admin-Bouton" type="submit" value="Générer" form="formParametres" />
<!-- remove onlick attribute and add a Id attribute in above line -->

<div id="syntheseOTP"></div>
```

Now make sure you add a click event handler in your scripts.

```
$('#AjaxButton').on('click',affOtp);

function affOtp(e) {  // add e as input parameter
                      // removed unnecessary wrapper
    e.preventDefault(); // this will now stop the click event.

    $("#syntheseOTP").html("Loading...."); // add loading text into div
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vue/ressources/affOtp.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { idEmploye: nom },
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                $("#syntheseOTP").html(msg); //refactored to use jquery syntax
            },
            error: function(resu, statut, erreur) {
                console.log(erreur);
                alert("papa");
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: The result is good for displaying the result of affOtp function, but the second fonctionnality doesn't work .. I think i 'm going to find another solution or create other button even if that's that don't want my boss ! Thanks to pass time to help me Rajshekar.

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl `second fonctionnality doesn't work` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: If i explain this easily as possible. Another programmer before me use the Générer button to submit and display an array on screen (this is the thing not work). And i must use same button to display another array, but i can't touch his code and add my functionnality to this. Because it's different things. I must use Submit and Button type together. You understood ? Or you want all page code .

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl yes understood. Now all you have to do is debug the existing code see what function is called and plugin your function call there.. If you dont know how to do it, you will have to post the other developers code as well..

Comment: thanks for your helf Rajskar i appreciate ! I'm going to debugg yes and fine a solution !

Comment: @TomLgl-dcl all the best :)